# Equal sign inside object destructuring curly braces

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

I saw this statement in Graphql directive definition:

```
const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
```

I know the part `const { resolve } = field;` means getting `resolve` property of the `field` object out and storing it in a local variable `resolve`. But what I'm coming across for the first time is the `= defaultFieldResolver` part. What does the equal sign do here? I've done a thorough google search but maybe I'm not aware of the right keyword to search or this is probably something new.

[Here's](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/#:%7E:text=const%20%7B%20resolve%20%3D%20defaultFieldResolver%20%7D%20%3D%20field%3B) the link of the article where I saw this.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It provides a default value if `field` doesn't have a `resolve` property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That means if `field` contains a `resolve` property, extract it:

```js
const defaultFieldResolver = 'defaultFieldResolver';

const field = { resolve: 'resolve' };

const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

console.log(resolve);
```

If `field` doesn't contain a `resolve` property, assign `defaultFieldResolver` to the `resolve` variable instead.

```js
const defaultFieldResolver = 'defaultFieldResolver';

const field = {};

const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

console.log(resolve);
```